# I have a HashSet<Prerequisite> pre. Is there a fast way to do HashSet<int> PreIDs = for each x do x.getID in Pre? (in Java)

Tags: java, class, methods, hashset

There is a class `Prerequisite`, it has a method `getID()`.

Instead of doing

```
HashSet<int> PreIDs = new HashSet<>();

for(Prerequisite p: pre// HashSet of Prerequisites)
{
   PreIDs.add(p.getID())
}
```

is there a more efficient or more concise way to call a method over a HashSet?

Comment: There pretty much isn't any more efficient way. What you have there is as good as it gets. *You* judge whether this is more concise: `pre.forEach(p -> preIDs.add(p.getID()))`

Comment: Thats a good one liner. I like it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @ernest_k said, there isn't any more efficient way in my opinion too. But we can write that whole logic in one line as below (if you are using Java 8 or above) using streams:

```java
Set<Integer> PreIDs = pre.stream()
    .map(Prerequisite::getID)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```